# FatalExecutionEngineError was detected at statement of calling MDIParent

Tags: c#, runtime-error

My winforms application is almost finished to deliver, but I am afraid of FatalExecutionEngineError which occurs frequently as I start application, debugger moves execution pointer at calling MDIParent from

```
    //program.cs  
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MDIParent()); // <--- here debugger returns backs
    }
```

**I have a dozens of forms and classes in my application and I can not figure out the actual problem , your help is highly appreciated.**

Error Message is Shown as Below:
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x791f5ace, on thread 0x804. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it. In fact the problem caused to me was working on Oracle Virtual Box .... most probably it was a memory heap issue. Anyway my problem was solved while working on actual machine.